# MYSQL condition inside case not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Here is the

sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a51734/5)

**1) [table:data_aoc]**

```
  | aoc_id | aoc_name | aoc_type | client_id |
  |------------------------------|-----------|
1 |  MA01  | sensor_1 |    4     |     1     |
2 |  MA02  | sensor_2 |    15    |     1     |
```

**2) table:data_log**

```
  | log_id | log_aoc_id | trans_type | trans_value | trans_date |
  |-------------------------------------------------------------|
1 |  x1a1  |    MA01    |      0     |     90      | 2017-10-20 |
2 |  afaf  |    MA01    |      0     |     90      | 2017-10-21 |
3 |  va12  |    MA02    |      0     |     10      | 2017-10-21 |
4 |  gag2  |    MA02    |      0     |     10      | 2017-11-25 |
```

**Expected Result**

```
Total value for MA02 should be 10 but it shows 20
```

my queries as follows

```
SELECT  
(CASE
WHEN a.aoc_type IN ('4')
THEN IFNULL((SUM(b.trans_value * case b.trans_type when '0' then -1 else 1 end)),0)

WHEN a.aoc_type IN ('15') 
THEN IFNULL((SUM(b.trans_value * case when b.trans_type='0' AND DATE(b.trans_date) <= DATE(NOW()) then -1 else 1 end)),0)

END) as total 
FROM data_aoc a
LEFT JOIN data_log b ON b.log_aoc_id = a.aoc_id
WHERE a.client_id='1'
GROUP BY a.aoc_name
ORDER BY a.aoc_id asc
```

Iam expecting when aoc_type is (15) it will sum the value within the date condition

```
DATE(b.trans_date) <= DATE(NOW())
```

but when i execute the queries, it produce result not within the date condition. *some timestamps are generated in advance beyond the NOW() date time.

The desired result should be:

```
| Total |
|-------|
| -180  |
|   10  |
```

But i get

```
| Total |
|-------|
| -180  |
|   0   |  <----- it should be 10 because of the date condition i put
```

thank you!

Comment: Do you maybe need to add aoc_type to your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: had Tested sadly still no desired result.

Comment: For query questions, post your table format, a sample data and the expected result.  it makes it much easier to help.

Comment: @Nic3500 Ok i had edited the question with sample & expected result

Comment: Ok sorry, I tried but your question needs to much rework.   WHERE a.client_id ...  This column does not exist in your sample data.  GROUP BY aaoc_name...  It should be a.aoc_name.  aaoc_name does not exist.  Then there are errors on the GROUP BY expression ...  Fix your question before we can help fix the original problem.

Comment: @Nic3500 ok i created a fiddle here nic http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a51734/5

Comment: Ok, completely disregard your post of tables, query and sqlfiddle.  In simple English sentences, can you describe what it is you are TRYING to do... ex: I am trying to get the sum of each XXX and YYY based on ???  The sum represents WHAT.  Having context of what things represent can help in this otherwise unclear question.

Comment: @DRapp if trans_type is = '0' it will make the current trans_value to -ve number or if trans_type is = '1' it will retain the trans_value. * i reedit the post and had post the desired result at bottom of it. iam confuse why the result for last row or 'MA02 ' is 0 not 10 as i had put date condition on the queries to sum the value only inside the date range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow-up of same findings from Don, And your clarification of don't count after, I came up with this query...  Pre-check on the date first and if after, multiply by zero, OTHERWISE, apply the +/- 1 factor.

```
SELECT
      SUM( b.trans_value * 
           CASE when (    a.aoc_type = '15'
                      AND b.trans_type = '0'
                      AND DATE(b.trans_date) > DATE(NOW())  )
                then 0
                when (    a.aoc_type = '4'
                      AND b.trans_type = '0' )
                  OR (    a.aoc_type = '15'
                      AND b.trans_type = '0'
                      AND DATE(b.trans_date) <= DATE(NOW())  )
                then -1 else 1 end ) as total
   FROM 
      data_aoc a
         LEFT JOIN data_log b 
            ON a.aoc_id = b.log_aoc_id
   WHERE 
      a.client_id='1'
   GROUP BY 
      a.aoc_name
   ORDER BY 
      a.aoc_id asc
```

[Also posted on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a51734/20)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working exactly as it should.
With the date clause I get:

```
Sensor 1 = -180
Sensor 2 = 0
```

If you break down the summing you get two rows to be summed for sensor #2
10 on 10-21 (before the date restriction so it's multiplied by -1)
and
10 on 11-25 (after the date restriction so it's multiplied by 1)

```
10 * -1 + 10 * 1 = 0
```

The sensor #2 reading is correctly 0.

I do not understand why you think it should be anything else.

Comment: The date clause is to make sure the value of sensor 2 should only be read before the date clause. meaning it should only read value with date at 2017-10-21 only, not more than DATE(NOW()) values.

Comment: The point is that the date clause isn't the problem, multiplying by `-1` is the problem. You don't want `SUM(10*1, 10*-1)`, you want `SUM(10*1, 10*0)`. Or, even better, don't do the dodgy multiplication at all, just exclude values using the CASE statement...  `SUM(CASE WHEN b.trans_type='0' AND DATE(b.trans_date) <= DATE(NOW()) THEN b.trans_value ELSE 0 END) `